# Deploying a new version of a Spring application to ElasticBeanstalk, @PreDestroy is not being called?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services

I'm working currently with Spring Boot, Tomcat, and AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I have several beans that I want to save a little bit of information to disk before restarting the server, then load it back in when the server restarts.

What I'm seeing is that the `@PostConstruct` annotated functions are getting called whenever the application starts, but I am never seeing the `@PreDestroy` getting called.

I was under the assumption that the context was being closed gracefully when I update the environment (single environment).  Is there something I need to add to the Application property to get it to call the `@PreDestroy`?

I'm using all annotations, and no XML configuration for this.

```
@Component
public class SomeStructs {

    static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BuzzStructs.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void onCreate(){
        log.info("Creating Buzz Structs!");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void onDelete(){
        log.info("Deleting Buzz Structs!");
        System.out.println("Deleting Junk");
    }
}
```

For this piece of code, the `@PostConstruct` is always called, but the `@PreDestroy` never is.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of pain and suffering, I figured out what was happening.

I was running my ELB on a T1.micro instance (free tier baby!).  Apparently it's so limited that it doesn't have enough memory for the JVM to shutdown properly, so every context refresh was accompanied by the JVM crashing.  JVM crashes = no shutdown sequence.

Solution was to up the instance size to a t2.small.  No longer free, but my application doesn't blow up anymore, which is nice.